# ¿Cómo crear consultas dinámicas sql y java?

Tags: java, sql, sintaxis

quiero saber como puedo hacer cosultas dinámicas sin conctatenar en la declaracion del **string**
osea mandar cosultas desde java para que se creen en mysql
 Encontré esto en foros, pero no funciona, da un error de syntaxis:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@campo = 'Alejandro' WHERE idAlumno = '1'' at line 1

```
public void actualizarDatos(String campo, String id, String nuevo_dato) {
    final String consulta = "DECLARE @campo VARCHAR(15)";
    final String consulta1 = "SET @campo = ?";
    final String consulta2 = "UPDATE ALUMNOS SET @campo = ? WHERE idAlumno = ?";
    Connection conn = conexion();

    try {
        PreparedStatement declaracion = conn.prepareStatement(consulta);

        declaracion= conn.prepareStatement(consulta1);
        declaracion.setString(1, campo);
        declaracion.executeUpdate();

        declaracion = conn.prepareStatement(consulta2);
        declaracion.setString(1, nuevo_dato);
        declaracion.setString(2, id);

        declaracion.executeUpdate();

        conn.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

El string de la consulta2 es lo que quiero hacer, pasar a la funcion el nombre del campo y meterlo a la consulta, saber eso ya me sirve para hacer las consultas dinamicas.

Me logueé en la terminal y probé hacerlo ahí y me decía el mismo error de sintaxis. Después adapté y probé estos dos ejemplos y otros más que encontré en los foros y me decía lo mismo  error de sintaxis y ni siquiera me dejaba usar el **DECLARE** cosa que con la consulta de java ni menciona:

```
DECLARE @ConsultaSQL NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @Tabla NVARCHAR(25)

SET @Tabla = 'Empleados'
SET @ConsultaSQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @Tabla

EXEC(@ConsultaSQL)

----------------
DECLARE @ConsultaSQL NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @Tabla NVARCHAR(25)

SET @Tabla = 'Empleados'
SET @ConsultaSQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @Tabla

EXEC(@ConsultaSQL)
```

Comment: No entiendo cual es la consulta dinamica que tratas de crear en tu programa...

Comment: @gbianchi perdon me falto escribir algo despues de la funcion

Comment: pero eso que vos queres se soluciona construyendo el string, sin pasar parametros, a mano...

Comment: @gbianchi no quiero concatenar

Comment: el nombre del campo? porque no?

Comment: No es solo el nombre del campo lo que esta abajo del post tampoco sirve lo del @campo es la ultima prueba que hice antes de rendirme pero si puedo hacer eso  de alguna manera puedo hacer el resto de cosas que quiero pregunto por eso porque es lo mas sencillo que probe

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer es algo casi prohibitivo en SQL. Para obtener mejor esa funcionalidad, sería bueno que aprendieras acerca de ORMs. Generar cadenas de código SQL de forma dinámica es la mejor forma de ser víctima de inyección de SQL.

Comment: Me uno a las opiniones de gbianchi y de @LuisCazares. ¿Podrías explicar lo que justifica el que quieras hacer algo tan peligroso? Es que en el código no sólo veo la posibilidad de inyección SQL, sino que al parecer quieres hasta permitir que se creen tablas y/o campos ¿? ¿A qué se debe eso? ¿qué hay del modelo de datos, de la consistencia, de la coherencia si dejas que cualquiera cree tablas/campos en tu sistema? ¿Te imaginas un bot intruso que cree  millones de tablas por ejemplo?

Comment: El usuario de la app solo puede conectarse a esa bd y tiene privilegios para los datos nada mas insert update y delete, antes de enviar datos para hacer consultas verifique que no se puedan introducir caracteres especiales pero aun asi no sabia que fuera tan peligroso ni que en la universidad te enseñaran de manera descuidada pero bueno ahi ni enseñana XD estoy aprendiendo casi por mi cuenta solo uso los pdf de ejercicios y hago vosas extras, pero gracias por la info igual es mejor que lo que pregunte

Comment: Está bien, estás aprendiendo. Pero imagina que pudieran borrar todos los datos de una tabla si envían la instrucción correcta o que un usuario no pueda guardar un dato correctamente por tu validación de caracteres.